# Is it safe to say that temperature is a measure of molecular activity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, atomic-physics, speed

In Wikipedia

Temperature is a physical quantity that expresses the hotness of matter or radiation.

There are three types of temperature scale: those, such as the SI scale, that are defined in terms of the average translational kinetic energy per freely moving microscopic particle, such as atom, molecule, or electron, in a body

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature

========

I wonder is it save to say that temperature is a measure of molecular activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can say that but it would be rather vague, because there are other physical concepts which might also be called a measure of molecular activity, such as energy, speed, fugacity, etc.

Temperature is property (in formal language, a function of state) of a system in thermal equilibrium, such that two systems at the same temperature will show no net heat flow between them when brought into thermal contact. In microscopic terms, it is a measure of the distribution of energy in the microscopic motions and positions in a system. A higher temperature gives a wider distribution.